# Showing that $-\ln{X} \sim \exp{\alpha}$ for $X \sim Beta(\alpha, 1)$

Tags: probability, statistics

The CDF for $X \sim Beta(\alpha,1)$ is given by:

$$F(x) = \frac{\int_{0}^{x}t^{\alpha-1}dt}{\int_{0}^{1} t^{\alpha-1}dt}$$

I am given to understand that $-\ln{X} \sim \exp(\alpha)$ if $\alpha > 0$.

How do I go about showing this? In all my attempts, I really don't know what to do with the presence of the natural logarithm term.

EDIT: If this is not so trivial, it might help to look at the [Kumaraswamy Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumaraswamy_distribution).

Comment: Actually you are given the PDF for X, not its CDF, hence one can deduce directly the PDF of $Y=u(X)$ from the PDF of $X$ thanks to the identity $$f_Y(y)=f_X(u^{-1}(y))\mathrm{Jac}(y)$$ where $\mathrm{Jac}$ denotes the Jacobian of the transformation $y\mapsto u^{-1}(y)$, instead of using the long road PDF of $X\to$ CDF of $X\to$ CDF of $Y\to$ PDF of $Y$. This is explained in many posts on the site (as well as in every decent textbook).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but I think you first need to explicitly [figure out the cdf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) of $X$, $F_X$, which [turns out to be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function):

$$ F_X(x):=F_X(x; \alpha,1) = x^\alpha. $$

Then, the usual approach:

$$P(Y:=-\ln X \leq y) = P\left(X\geq {\rm e}^{-y}\right) = 1-F_X\left({\rm e}^{- y}\right) =1- {\rm e}^{-\alpha y}$$

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought the expression I gave was the CDF for $X$. How do you justify getting rid of the integral and the Beta function in the denominator? I think that was the source of my troubles.

Comment: Just follow my links (or elsewhere) for properties of special functions beta/gamma and related.

Comment: Right. I guess it's not something so straightforward to have been able to do myself without the right information about these special functions?

Comment: @christoph yes, it is an elementary convergent improper integral ($1-\alpha<1$): $\int_0^x t^{\alpha-1}dt  = \lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_\epsilon^x t^{\alpha-1}dt = \lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+} t^\alpha/\alpha |_\epsilon^x = x^\alpha/\alpha. $

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x) = -\log x$, hence $Y = g(X) = -\log X$, so that $X = g^{-1}(Y) = e^{-Y}$.  Then $$F_Y(y) = \Pr[Y \le y] = \Pr[-\log X \le y] = \Pr[X \ge e^{-y}] = 1 - F_X(e^{-y}).$$  Then differentiation of the CDF gives $$f_Y(y) = f_X(e^{-y})e^{-y}$$ by the chain rule.  Now if $X \sim \mathrm{Beta}(\alpha,1)$, then $f_X(x) \propto x^{\alpha - 1}$, hence we have $$f_Y(y) \propto e^{-y(\alpha-1)} e^{-y} = e^{-\alpha y}$$ which is clearly exponential with rate parameter $\alpha$.  There is no need to explicitly compute $F_X$; it suffices to know the PDF of $X$.  Indeed, this approach can be used even when $X \sim \mathrm{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ in general, although the resulting distribution for $Y$ is not generally exponential.  I leave it to the reader as an exercise to determine whether such a distribution has a name.

Comment: +1 Still, is there a "self-contained" way of computing this cdf? (No restrictions on $\alpha$.)